# PHP system notify send

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to show a notification in certain situation. I saw you could do this with system() function. Except I cant get it to work ;).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
system("notify-send 'Text here?'");
system('notify-send "Text here?"');
```

Could some one tell me what I am doing wrong? or is my set up wrong? I want to create the notification on Ubuntu with notify-send and PHP

greetings

Comment: Try command: "whereis notify-send" to find the full path of "notify-send", then use it in your code and try again.

Comment: changed to system('/usr/bin/notify-send "sdfsd"');
still no luck

Comment: Try to run your PHP code from console as root, like "sudo php /path/to/your/script.php". If works, problem should be the privilege.

Comment: It was a privilege problem. Thank you Alix!

Answer (score 2):

Ok even though this is kinda solved but I'd like to add some notes/info here,
As far as i know the issue should be that the user that runs PHP isn't the same user that runs the desktop session (gnome/kde/etc), so the PHP executable doesn't have the permission to show a notification on that screen.
For me i solved it by making the PHP executable run under the same user that owns the session (eg if my username is called `abc`, I've set PHP to run under the same `abc` user, and I also had to export the display by using `export DISPLAY=:0`, 
So my whole exec/system call was like this

```
exec("export DISPLAY=:0; notify-send 'title' '$message' ")
```

Comment: I should try that, might be the only thing that is needed

Answer (score 0):

I turned the export DISPLAY approach into a /usr/bin script.  I tested it via remote ssh into the system and have used it successfully in bash scripts/crons.  http://pastebin.com/h11p2HtN
What I'm curious about is how to display desktop notification on the login screen.  It would be nice to display some information regarding init scripts.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to get this working with php, but every solution I saw here is crappy, either running the apache as your user or exporting the display and so on.

I wrote this little script in node.js, having the advantage being run by the desktop user, no additional environment variables need to be exported:

1. Install node.js (should be easy as download, configure, make, make-install)
2. Create a directory for this app, e. g. mkdir ~/message
3. Install express-framework: cd ~/message ; npm install express
4. Create the script
5. Run it ... "node ./script-name.js"

Now you can fire requests like localhost:5555/?message=Hello+World

Worked for me, after I wasted hours trying to get this with apache, php, cgi or whatever.

Script:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.contentType('text/html');
  res.send(200, '');
  child = exec("/usr/bin/notify-send 'Message' '" + req.query.message + "'", function (error, stdout, stderr) {});
});

app.listen(5555);
```

Comment: OP asks for a PHP solution, not a Node one